# how to get the result of Email Intent? the resultCode isn't correct

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

How can you catch the result of Email Intent?

I tried with this:

```
val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
emailIntent.type = "message/rfc822"
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("xxxx@gmail.com"))
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "title")
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "$sendData")

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."), RESULT_SEND_EMAIL)
```

And this doesn't get `Activity.RESULT_OK` when it sends correctly. Instead, it gets `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == RESULT_SEND_EMAIL) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sending success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sending cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can you catch the result of Email Intent?

There is no result. [`ACTION_SEND` has no output](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND).

Comment: So, there isn't any solution?

Comment: @c-an: Correct. What the user does with your request to send something is up to the user and the app that they chose.